# Ternary operator in Influx flux

Tags: influxdb, fluxlang

I am doing a join in influx to get the first and last values for a interval and then getting the difference.

```
Preset = 600

FirstValues = from(bucket: "Historian/oneday")
  |> range(start: dashboardTime)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => 
    r._measurement == "TestMeasurement" and
    r._field =="Value"  and
    r.Loc=="TXS"
  )
 |>window(every:15m)
 |>first()


 LastValues = from(bucket: "Historian/oneday")
  |> range(start: dashboardTime)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => 
    r._measurement == "TestMeasurement" and
    r._field =="Value"  and
    r.Loc=="TXS"
  )
 |>window(every:15m)
 |>last()

 CombinedValues = join (
    tables:{first:FirstValues,last:LastValues},
    on:["_stop","_start"]
 )
 totaliser = CombinedValues
                |>map(fn: (r) => ({   
                    _time: r._start,
                    //Want to do this, r._value_first < r._value_last ? Preset : r._value_first
                    _value: r._value_first - r._value_last
                }))
 totaliser
 |>window(every:inf)
```

This works fine till the time difference returns a positive number.

But if the 1st value from join returns is less than 2nd value , I want to update that with a perset value.

Ex:

```
Preset = 600

totaliser = CombinedValues
                |>map(fn: (r) => ({   
                    _time: r._start,

                    //Want to do this, r._value_first < r._value_last ? Preset : r._value_first

                    _value: r._value_first - r._value_last
                }))
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for a solution in Flux or InfluxQL?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I am looking for a solution in Flux.

Answer (score -2):

Conditional logic is pretty new to Flux, but it does exist. Currently there is only `if`, `else if`, and `else`:

```
// Pattern
if <condition> then <action> else <alternative-action>

// Example
if color == "green" then "008000" else "ffffff"
```

But this will be expanded with time.

https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/query-data/guides/conditional-logic/

Comment: Thanks, we are using influx db 1.7.6. Not keen to update to 2.0 , on production, as it's in alpha stage.

Comment: You can use Flux with 1.7

Comment: If and else with flux 1.7 results error message,  "Error: failed to compile query:type error 5:1-5:3: undefined identifier "if" "

Comment: Hmm, this was added to Flux recently; but I thought it was available in 1.7.6. Please allow me to reach out to someone internally and find out :)